# Adding a Google account via GNOME returns an error

Tags: 20.04, java, language-support, locale, utf-8

I've been attempting to connect my school Google Drive account to my computer (I'm connected via my personal email). Here are the steps:

1. Click on Google in the Online Accounts tab
2. Type in my email and click to continue to GNOME.

I'm returned the following error:

[image]

So far, I've reached out to the IT department and they suggested that the issue is that my computer has a misconfigured locale. They included a [link](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/52641220?hl=en) a support request for a Chromebook issue that might be related.

I followed the directions from the thread and this is what was outputted:

```
defarm@homeone:locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE= 
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`locale -a` shows `en_US.UTF-8`

When I enter into /usr/share/locale there are 266 directories (I ran a code, which is explained in the next step), including en and en_US.

`sudo locale-gen` generates locales (and takes a while). It includes en_US.UTF-8, en_US.8859-1, and en_US.ISO-8859-15. I check /usr/share and I don't see en_US.UTF-8 (but I don't think I'm supposed to). I `cd` into /locale/en_US and there is one file: kf5_entry.desktop. Opening this up in gedit returns:

[image]

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update: I have also attempted to reach out to the Shibboleth Consortium, but do not have privileges to do so within my organization. I am unable to submit a bug request or access the Slack.

Comment: Your locale seems correct to me.

Comment: Right. Is there a line of code somewhere locally that is written incorrectly? Is it on Shibboleth? I subbed to the users list and am in the process of sending the owner a summary of what's going on. It's like waiting in line at customs, but from the comfort of my chair.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that it should be sending `en_US.UTF-8`, not `en-us.utf-8`.  So I believe there are two bugs here: one apparently in GNOME for sending a hyphen instead of an underscore (as your `locale` output shows you should have), and the one in Shibboleth IdP (patched [as noted in their response to you] but probably not released and definitely not deployed) for not catching the java exception when it received that illegal header.